# Changing boolean var in ruby without having warnings

Tags: ruby

I don't want to redefine the boolean var another time i want just to change it value so i want to know how to do it correctly ? or how to hide these warnings .
this is my code :

```
Continu=true
puts Continu
Continu=false
if !Continu
puts 1
end
```

this is the result of the execution :
[image: result of the execution]

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with boolean. Neither is it about variables. You do not even have a variable there. The issue is about constants.

Comment: yeah i didn't know that if you start your var with capital letter ruby will think it is a constant , i want to have a boolean var not a constant @sawa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a variable with the first letter as a capital letter, ruby will think it is a constant.

```
continue = true
puts continue
continue = false
if !continue
  puts 1
end
```